# Select com varias Procedures

Tags: sql-server

Bom Dia,
Como eu faço para realizar o select com varias procedure? Eu tenho uma procedure que retorna 3 medias de 1 mes especifico. Agora preciso executar essa proc 12x no select. Tipo: SELECT (SP_JANEIRO), (SP_FEVEREIRO), (SP_MARCO).....Alguem sabe como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode fazer `select` com `procedures`.

O que você pode fazer é o contrário ou substituir as procedures por `Function`

Answer (score 1):

Aqui estão alguns exemplos para mostrar como fazer. Pode usar stored procedure ou table-valued function.

Scalar function nâo é adequado, porque devolve somente um resultado e três médias são requerido. Também scalar functions são muito ineficiente.

```
USE AdventureWorks2016CTP3;
GO

-- Exemplo 1: procedure que devolve os resultados por OUT parameters
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.up_Medias1
(
    @PrimeiroDoMes date,
    @MediaSubTotal money OUT,
    @MediaTaxAmt money OUT,
    @MediaFreight money OUT
)
AS

IF DATEPART(DAY, @PrimeiroDoMes) <> 1
    RAISERROR(N'@PrimeiroDoMes dia deve ser 1.', 12, 1);

SELECT @MediaSubTotal = AVG(SubTotal), @MediaTaxAmt = AVG(TaxAmt), @MediaFreight = AVG(Freight)
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN @PrimeiroDoMes AND EOMONTH(@PrimeiroDoMes);
GO

-- Testar o procedure
DECLARE @PrimDoMes date = N'2014-01-01';
DECLARE @MedSubTotal money;
DECLARE @MedTaxAmt money;
DECLARE @MedFreight money;

EXEC dbo.up_Medias1 @PrimDoMes, @MedSubTotal OUTPUT, @MedTaxAmt OUTPUT, @MedFreight OUTPUT;

-- Apresentar os resultados
SELECT @MedSubTotal AS 'Media SubTotal', @MedTaxAmt AS 'Media TaxAmt', @MedFreight AS 'Media Freight';
```

[image: Resultado do exemplo 1]

```
-- Exemplo 2: procedure que devolve os resultados por result set
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.up_Medias2
(
    @PrimeiroDoMes date
)
AS

IF DATEPART(DAY, @PrimeiroDoMes) <> 1
    RAISERROR(N'@PrimeiroDoMes dia deve ser 1.', 12, 1);

SELECT AVG(SubTotal) AS 'MediaSubTotal', AVG(TaxAmt) AS 'MediaTaxAmt', AVG(Freight) AS 'MediaFreight'
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN @PrimeiroDoMes AND EOMONTH(@PrimeiroDoMes);
GO

-- Testar o procedure
DECLARE @PrimDoMes date = N'2014-01-01';

EXEC dbo.up_Medias2 @PrimDoMes;
```

[image: Resultado do exemplo 2]

```
-- Exemplo 3: procedure que devolve medias por 12 meses
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.up_Medias3
(
    @Ano int
)
AS

SELECT YEAR(OrderDate) AS 'Ano', MONTH(OrderDate) AS 'Mês', AVG(SubTotal) AS 'MediaSubTotal', AVG(TaxAmt) AS 'MediaTaxAmt', AVG(Freight) AS 'MediaFreight'
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(@Ano, 1, 1) AND DATEFROMPARTS(@Ano, 12, 31)
    GROUP BY YEAR(OrderDate), MONTH(OrderDate)
    ORDER BY Ano, Mês;
GO

-- Testar o procedure
DECLARE @Ano int = 2013;

EXEC dbo.up_Medias3 @Ano;
GO
```

[image: Resultado do exemplo 3.]

```
-- Exemplo 4: function que devolve medias por 12 meses
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_Medias4
(
    @Ano int
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (SELECT YEAR(OrderDate) AS 'Ano', MONTH(OrderDate) AS 'Mês', AVG(SubTotal) AS 'MediaSubTotal', AVG(TaxAmt) AS 'MediaTaxAmt', AVG(Freight) AS 'MediaFreight'
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(@Ano, 1, 1) AND DATEFROMPARTS(@Ano, 12, 31)
    GROUP BY YEAR(OrderDate), MONTH(OrderDate));
GO

-- Testar o function
SELECT *
    FROM dbo.fn_Medias4(2013)
    ORDER BY Ano, Mês;
GO
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

CoDoRNeX, normalmente utilizamos functions quando queremos retornar algum dado a ser utilizado em um Script DDL, devido a esta natureza uma função não pode inserir, atualizar, ou apagar dados.

Se a sua procedure não modifica nenhum dado do banco, então é deve ser facil conveter a mesma para uma procedure, e como disse que a sua procedure retorna três valores, então o melhor a fazer é fazer uma `table valued-function`.

vamos pegar por exemplo a seguinte função que retorna três colunas:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CalcMedia(@mes int) 
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT 1 AS Media1, 2 AS Media2, 3 AS Media3
)
```

Então você poderia chamar ela da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT 
    Mes1.Media1, Mes1.Media2, Mes1.Media3,
    Mes2.Media1, Mes2.Media2, Mes2.Media3,
    Mes3.Media1, Mes3.Media2, Mes3.Media3,
    Mes4.Media1, Mes4.Media2, Mes4.Media3,
    Mes5.Media1, Mes5.Media2, Mes5.Media3,
    Mes6.Media1, Mes6.Media2, Mes6.Media3,
    Mes7.Media1, Mes7.Media2, Mes7.Media3,
    Mes8.Media1, Mes8.Media2, Mes8.Media3,
    Mes9.Media1, Mes9.Media2, Mes9.Media3,
    Mes10.Media1, Mes10.Media2, Mes10.Media3,
    Mes11.Media1, Mes11.Media2, Mes11.Media3,
    Mes12.Media1, Mes12.Media2, Mes12.Media3
FROM 
    dbo.CalcMedia(1) AS Mes1,
    dbo.CalcMedia(2) AS Mes2,
    dbo.CalcMedia(3) AS Mes3,
    dbo.CalcMedia(4) AS Mes4,
    dbo.CalcMedia(5) AS Mes5,
    dbo.CalcMedia(6) AS Mes6,
    dbo.CalcMedia(7) AS Mes7,
    dbo.CalcMedia(8) AS Mes8,
    dbo.CalcMedia(9) AS Mes9,
    dbo.CalcMedia(10) AS Mes10,
    dbo.CalcMedia(11) AS Mes11,
    dbo.CalcMedia(12) AS Mes12
```

Mas se realmente precisa precisa executar as procedures, afinal você pode precisar inserir algum dado enquanto executa faz o calculo da Media.

Neste caso você pode inserir o retorno da função em uma tabela temporaria, então vamos pegar a seguinte store procedure como base:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CalcMedia @mes int    
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT 1 AS Media1, 2 AS Media2, 3 AS Media3
END
```

então faça assim:

```
DECLARE @medias AS TABLE (
    MesID int primary key identity,
    Media1 decimal(12, 2) not null,
    Media2 decimal(12, 2) not null,
    Media3 decimal(12, 2) not null
)

INSERT INTO @medias EXEC dbo.CalcMedia @mes = 1
INSERT INTO @medias EXEC dbo.CalcMedia @mes = 2
INSERT INTO @medias EXEC dbo.CalcMedia @mes = 3
INSERT INTO @medias EXEC dbo.CalcMedia @mes = 4
INSERT INTO @medias EXEC dbo.CalcMedia @mes = 5
INSERT INTO @medias EXEC dbo.CalcMedia @mes = 6
INSERT INTO @medias EXEC dbo.CalcMedia @mes = 7
INSERT INTO @medias EXEC dbo.CalcMedia @mes = 8
INSERT INTO @medias EXEC dbo.CalcMedia @mes = 9
INSERT INTO @medias EXEC dbo.CalcMedia @mes = 10
INSERT INTO @medias EXEC dbo.CalcMedia @mes = 11
INSERT INTO @medias EXEC dbo.CalcMedia @mes = 12

SELECT 
    Mes1.Media1, Mes1.Media2, Mes1.Media3,
    Mes2.Media1, Mes2.Media2, Mes2.Media3,
    Mes3.Media1, Mes3.Media2, Mes3.Media3,
    Mes4.Media1, Mes4.Media2, Mes4.Media3,
    Mes5.Media1, Mes5.Media2, Mes5.Media3,
    Mes6.Media1, Mes6.Media2, Mes6.Media3,
    Mes7.Media1, Mes7.Media2, Mes7.Media3,
    Mes8.Media1, Mes8.Media2, Mes8.Media3,
    Mes9.Media1, Mes9.Media2, Mes9.Media3,
    Mes10.Media1, Mes10.Media2, Mes10.Media3,
    Mes11.Media1, Mes11.Media2, Mes11.Media3,
    Mes12.Media1, Mes12.Media2, Mes12.Media3
FROM 
    @medias AS Mes1,
    @medias AS Mes2,
    @medias AS Mes3,
    @medias AS Mes4,
    @medias AS Mes5,
    @medias AS Mes6,
    @medias AS Mes7,
    @medias AS Mes8,
    @medias AS Mes9,
    @medias AS Mes10,
    @medias AS Mes11,
    @medias AS Mes12
WHERE 
    Mes1.MesID = 1 AND
    Mes2.MesID = 2 AND
    Mes3.MesID = 3 AND
    Mes4.MesID = 4 AND
    Mes5.MesID = 5 AND
    Mes6.MesID = 6 AND
    Mes7.MesID = 7 AND
    Mes8.MesID = 8 AND
    Mes9.MesID = 9 AND
    Mes10.MesID = 10 AND
    Mes11.MesID = 11 AND
    Mes12.MesID = 12
```